# ActivityNotFound - Launching Google Map using Intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, geolocation, gps

I am writing a program in which i am user to launch Google Map in Android, to launch Google Map i am using Intent but getting problem.

**Error says:**

```
 android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3395)
```

**Logcat:-**

```
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=?q=pizza+hut48.89364,2.33739&z=16 }
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1580)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3434)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3395)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3605)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3573)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1.onClick(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:41)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
12-13 15:00:15.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5819):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 15:00:23.730: I/Process(5819): Sending signal. PID: 5819 SIG: 9
```

Code **to Launch Google Map**, to show nearby PizzaHut using Intent

```
 double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
 double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
 String uriBegin = latitude + "," + longitude;
 String uriString = "?q=pizza+hut" + uriBegin + "&z=16";
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this url
change query and location parameters accordingly
here q is spcifying your query ll is your latitude and longitude and z is for zoom level

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=pizza+hut&ll=-33.867701,151.208471&z=12
```

Add this piece of code in your app

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://maps.google.com/?q=pizza+hut&ll=-33.867701,151.208471&z=12");
     Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
     intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
     startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please make sure that you added the url correctly. Check my edited code. it shows a popup to open url using internet or maps and works on both options.

Comment: thank you buddy :) cheers   and where can i get the list of query like: pizza+hut .... i need complete list

Comment: you can try different words here it is custom search and it will respond accordingly.

Comment: ok any idea if i don't want to show dialog, in short if directly want to launch via Google Maps only not want to show option for internet

Comment: You can try following line before your startActivity intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

Comment: as you can see in my above code, i am already using those, but still getting option for internet as well

Comment: Please check edited code. Its working. I am getting Google maps directly without dialog box

Comment: yeah i agree with @VaibhavAgarwal If you want to get rid of the dialog you can give the intent a hint as to which package you want to use. Before the startActivity() add this: intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

Answer (score 1):

To show **nearby Pizza Hut restaurants** using *current Location* of user and to launch **Google Map without dialog**.

If you want to get rid of the dialog you can give the intent a hint as to which package you want to use. Before the ***startActivity()*** add this:

**`intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");`**

finally your code ***should look like this***:

```
double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
String uriBegin = latitude + "," + longitude;
String uriString = "https://maps.google.com/?q=pizza+hut&ll=" + uriBegin + "&z=12";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",   "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```